# Symfony 2 create database command fail, with Schema Exception message

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Good Day:
I had a Symfony 2 DB that worked perfectly and then had to make some changes on the DB, I have removed one of the Entities and added an other entity. I did not find the way to update again my DB so I removed all the tables manually hoping to create it again. update schema command does not work; I am receiving the following error:

```
...# php app/console doctrine:database:create
Created database for connection named `eregistry`
...# php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Eregistry
Generating entities for namespace "Eregistry"
  > backing up Fields.php to Fields.php~
  > generating Eregistry\EventBundle\Entity\Fields
  > backing up FieldEvent.php to FieldEvent.php~
  > generating Eregistry\EventBundle\Entity\FieldEvent
  > backing up Participant.php to Participant.php~
  > generating Eregistry\EventBundle\Entity\Participant
  > backing up Event.php to Event.php~
  > generating Eregistry\EventBundle\Entity\Event
  > backing up Modality.php to Modality.php~
  > generating Eregistry\EventBundle\Entity\Modality
  > backing up Person.php to Person.php~
  > generating Eregistry\EventBundle\Entity\Person
  > backing up Domain.php to Domain.php~
  > generating Eregistry\EventBundle\Entity\Domain
  > backing up FieldData.php to FieldData.php~
  > generating Eregistry\EventBundle\Entity\FieldData
...# php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                 
  The table with name 'eregistry.event' already exists.  


doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [--force] [--em[="..."]]
...#
```

The database was freshly created, how come that it is giving me and exception saying that the table already exists? 
What could be the cause of this issue?
Regards
Abel

Comment: Are you sure your new entity doesn't have the same table name as another entity?

Comment: The new class is called _participant_ and it is not even mentioned in the error, the one mentioned is _event_ and event is the first class that is supposed to be created when the update schema is executed.What I mean is that there is not even attempts of doing any thing with the new class. I think that the error is related to something else.